# Strapi Issue : main.cd1c939f.js:2 Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:1337/admin/init'

Tags: node.js, strapi

Its like you're facing a Strapi-related issue where the connection to 'http://localhost:1337/admin/init' is being refused. The suggested solution is to rebuild Strapi using the command "npm run build."

When you run "npm run build," it triggers the build process for your Strapi project. This process may involve tasks such as transpiling code, bundling assets, and preparing the application for production. By doing this, you might resolve any issues related to the initialization of the admin interface or changes made to the public URL in your server.js file.